# Select items inside a cart and upgrade Cart's holding Counter

Tags: javascript

On this website I'm working on i runned into a new task I need to resolve before I move on.

While adding items into the cart, the counter adds as wanted the number of items inside the cart.
But, and that is how far I managed to go on my own for the moment, if the user wants to remove an item, the counter resets back to 0 and I'm aware of why. I set up

```
var qty = document.querySelector('.total-qty')    qty.innerText = 0
```

If i would add 2 T-shirt and 1 Album and delete the Album, the counter goes back to 0 although there are still 2 items inside the cart.

How do I collect each inserted item and upon the item being removed to update the counter properly to the items remaining inside the cart?There is also the same issue if the user tries to change the number of items while using the input spinner.

Do i loop through all the rows inside the cart and from there i target the quantity?

```
function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    var qty = document.querySelector('.total-qty')
    qty.innerText = 0
    updateCartTotal()
    CartIsEmpty()
}


function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('product_description_h1')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('product_price_button_price-2')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('product_image')[0].src
    var dressing = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('dressing_tab')[0].value
    var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName('total-qty')[0].innerText
    for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
        var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName('total-qty')[i];
            itemCount.innerText=parseInt(itemCount.innerText)+1;
        }
    var id = shopItem.dataset.itemId
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc, dressing, id)
    updateCartTotal()
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gracee1989/8d3sexo0/39/

Comment: the questions of the tipe "look my code and fix it" are a little confusing to understand and they don't grap good attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all the quantity inputs after removing one and reduce their values to get the new total. I moved the `quantityInputs` variable from `ready` into the global scope to achieve this in your JSFiddle but you can declare it again inside `removeCartItem` if you really want:

```
function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    const total = Array.from(quantityInputs).reduce((a, c) => a + Number(c.value), 0);
    var qty = document.querySelector('.total-qty')
    qty.innerText = total;
    updateCartTotal()
}
```

Here the reduce works by giving it a starting value - in this case 0 - which is referenced by the variable `a`. It then takes the value from each input in sequence and adds it to the last.

On a broader note, you might want to think about storing all the cart values in a data struture like an object, instead of reading from the DOM every time you want to update one. It will make it much easier to keep track of the state of the cart.

Comment: It works as needed, thanks for this. Also biggest point goes for the explanation underneath. As im study what you did on `const total` there is no wonder why i couldn't achieve it on my own. On another point where do i start to learn about storing all the cart values in a data structure like an object?

Comment: There's nothing that magic about reduce - it's very similar to the for loops you were using elsewhere, but allows you to avoid declaring lots of temporary variables. If you want a proper introduction to JS then I can recommend the relatively inexpensive Codecademy, but freeCodeCamp or any well reviewed beginner's books would also be a good place to start.